# Grails connection timeout during large fileupload

Tags: tomcat, grails, file-upload, timeout

I want to prevent the `SocketTimeoutException` that occurs after about 1 minute if a user tries to upload a large file from an upload form in my Grails web application. I know this is a Tomcat thing rather than a Grails thing, but I'm struggling a bit to modify `server.xml` using the `eventConfigureTomcat` event block in `_Events.groovy`.

According to the [tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) there is a `disableUploadTimeout` property that I should set to `true` on the connector, but when I try this in the `eventConfigureTomcat` block, I get the following error when my app starts up:

```
| Running Grails application
| Error Server failed to start: No such property: disableUploadTimeout for class: org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

The contents of my `_Events.groovy` looks like this:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    tomcat.connector.disableUploadTimeout = "true"
}
```

And that error does make sense - according to the javadoc, there is no property `disableUploadTimeout` on that connector implementation.

What am I doing wrong? How should I be setting this property, or is there some other way to prevent long running file uploads from timing out?

Comment: what's the exact error message you get in catalina.out when the timeout occurs?

Comment: Note that, according to the docs you linked, `disableUploadTimeout` defaults to `true`, and you should set it to `false` so that you can set a longer timeout period for `connectionUploadTimeout`.  (Unfortunately, I don't know how to properly set those values though.)

Answer (score 3):

haven't checked it, but taking a look at the tomcat documentation, the configuration you want to modify seems to be an attribute of the Connector.

The Connector has a method called [setAttribute](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). So I guess you'll succeed with the following code:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = { tomcat ->
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute('disableUploadTimeout', true); //may 'true'
}
```

have to admit that I couldn't test this code myself...

Update: according to @Charles-Wood , it has to be set to `false` and not `true`.

PS: if you post more information on how to reproduce your problem, I will give it a try

Comment: my connector is null. Any clue?